# How to perform a remote Solr core backup through SolrJ client?

Tags: solr, backup, solrj

I want to write a java client based on SolrJ which pulls the entire core data to a file from a remote Solr server. Later on I want to replay this file to another remote Solr server core.

What is the best method to implement this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's now possible with latest Solr versions.

To achieve backup on one Solr Server and restore on another one needs to do the following:

1. For each Solr installation in solr.xml setup backup repository to point to some shared drive. For example, one can use HDFS (this config requires `-Dsolr.hdfs.home=...` to be added into start script):

```xml
<solr>
...
<backup>
    <repository name="hdfs-repo" class="org.apache.solr.core.backup.repository.HdfsBackupRepository" default="false">
      <str name="location">${solr.hdfs.home}/backup</str>
      <str name="solr.hdfs.home">${solr.hdfs.home:}</str>
      <str name="solr.hdfs.confdir">${solr.hdfs.confdir:}</str>
    </repository>
</backup>
</solr>
```

2. Create backup from one server:

```java
SolrClient client1 = ...;
CollectionAdminRequest.Backup request1 = new CollectionAdminRequest.Backup(oldCollectionName, backupName);
request1.setRepositoryName("hdfs-repo");
request1.process(client1);
```

3. Then restore from backup on another server:

```java
SolrClient client2 = ...;
CollectionAdminRequest.Restore request2 = new CollectionAdminRequest.Restore(newCollectionName, backupName);
request2.setRepositoryName("hdfs-repo");
request2.process(client2);
```

This example works with Solr 7.5, but looks like the feature was already there in 6.6 (See [Backup/Restore in 6.6](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/making-and-restoring-backups.html#standalone-mode-backups)).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no such functionality in solr nor in solrj.

But if you have **all fields stored** in your index, you just could read out all documents and store them the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

Check if it applies to your case:

[Backup](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrReplication#HTTP_API) - You can perform a backup, however the backup will be created on the Server only.

> Create a backup on master if there are committed index data in the
>   server, otherwise do nothing. This is useful to take periodic backups.

You can use [Solr replication](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrReplication) to replicate the Content of the Index to any Remote Solr server.

So you can either replicate your index to a local box and then replicate it again to a remote box OR backup and just transfer the contents to a remote box.